# Cannot install ipa on device

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning, ipa, xcode5.1

I have signed a code with a distribution provisioning profile but when I generated the ipa in XCode 5.1 (Save for Enterprise/Adhoc Deployment), the app does not install in my device. I have checked that the distribution profile is properly aligned to the production certificate that is installed in my Macbook. Any reasons or solutions so that I can install my app? Thanks!

Comment: Is your `Device UUID` added to the Provisioning Profile, and are you using `Adhoc Distribution Provisioning Profile`?

Comment: No. I am using an "App Store" distribution provisioning profile.

Comment: What is the error message you getting while trying to install?

Comment: It got stuck on "Installing.." when I sync the app on iTunes while I received an error message "A valid provisioning file for this executable was not found" when I tried installing it using xCode.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure you are using `Adhoc Distribution Provisioning Profile`, not `AppStore Distribution Provisioning Profile`. AppStore Distribution Profile is required to distribute app from App Store, in your case you need to do following things in your **[Developer Account](https://developer.apple.com/iphone)**.

1. Add your Device in Devices List.
2. Create an Adhoc Distribution Provisioning Profile.
3. Select and check all the Devices listed.
4. Sign with the Distribution Certificate, and Adhoc Profile.
5. Create Adhoc Build, create IPA, and install.

Visit [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html) for more information.

Hope it helps.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks but I would want to ask why? Can't I use the App Store Distribution provisioning profile to generate an ipa for me to check my app?

Comment: @RaiKing, No, that is for distribution through App Store, where there is no limit of devices, anyone can install, while if you wan to install without App Store, you need to add your device and give authority to install, and using Adhoc Profiles, you can add your device for installations.. See this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html

Comment: But if anyone can install the app with the App Store distribution provisioning profile, why isn't it installing in the device? Sorry for asking a silly question hehe. I just want to understand why. I appreciate your replies here.

Comment: Have you downloaded the app through App Store? No, it is created by your XCode, and you are trying to install directly. Through App Store, its a different process.

Comment: Ah. Just to confirm. So, 1) App Store distribution provisioning profiles don't allow apps to be installed directly from xCode. 2) Apps signed with App Store distribution provisioning profiles can only be installed thru App Store. 3) If I want to test my app before submitting to App Store, I should sign it with Adhoc distribution provisioning profiles and not App Store.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any supporting documents (from Apple) for it? I would want to make a reference out of it.